# java.time.format.DateTimeParseException could not be parsed at index 0

Tags: java, gson, java-time, datetime-parsing, localdate

I am trying to tell Gson how to parse `LocalDateTime` and `LocalDate`, but I'm getting this error, which looks to me like it should match the format. I'm thinking there's either something I don't understand about parsing dates or something I don't understand about Gson.

> java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2017101800000700' could not be parsed at index 0

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(LocalDateTime.class, new JsonDeserializer<LocalDateTime>() {
    @Override
    public LocalDateTime deserialize(JsonElement json, Type type, JsonDeserializationContext jsonDeserializationContext) throws JsonParseException {
        return LocalDateTime.parse(json.getAsJsonPrimitive().getAsString(), DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS"));
    }
  }).registerTypeAdapter(LocalDate.class, new JsonDeserializer<LocalDate>() {
    @Override
    public LocalDate deserialize(JsonElement json, Type type, JsonDeserializationContext jsonDeserializationContext) throws JsonParseException {
        return LocalDate.parse(json.getAsJsonPrimitive().getAsString(), DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd"));
    }
  }).create();
```

Comment: Well 2017101800000700 doesn't fit yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS - you haven't got enough digits. (After the date, there's 00000700, giving HHmmss of 000007, leaving only 00 for SSS.)

Comment: But I suspect the 0700 is actually meant to be a time zone offset from UTC.

Comment: @JonSkeet The only strange thing (if 0700 is an offset) is the lack of a `+` or `-` sign, so it'd be an ambiguous offset. Or the absence of a sign means positive?

Comment: @Hugo: agreed, that's pretty odd.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [@Jon Skeet said in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46899038/java-time-format-datetimeparseexception-could-not-be-parsed-at-index-0#comment80745553_46899038), your pattern has 1 extra digit when compared to the input string, so `yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS` won't work: the input `2017101800000700` has 16 digits, while the pattern `yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS` expects 17.

---

Although the last part (`0700`) looks like an [UTC offset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset), it's missing a `+` or `-` sign (so it should be `+0700` or `-0700`). The offset represents the difference from UTC, and without a sign, it's ambiguous: you can't say if it's ahead or behind UTC.

And even if it's really an offset, I couldn't find a way to parse without a sign: I tried with [all the available options](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html#appendPattern-java.lang.String-) and none worked. A sign is always required, so parsing it as an offset is not possible, **unless you make an arbitrary assumption (such as *"it's positive"*) and change the input manually**, like this:

```
// assuming the offset "0700" is positive (7 hours ahead UTC)
String dateStr = "2017101800000700";

// insert the "+" manually, so input becomes 201710180000+0700
dateStr = dateStr.substring(0, 12) + "+" + dateStr.substring(12, 16);
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMddHHmmXX");
System.out.println(LocalDateTime.parse(dateStr, fmt)); // 2017-10-18T00:00
```

This will result in a `LocalDateTime` equals to:

> 2017-10-18T00:00

---

Another alternative is to treat `07` as seconds and the last 2 zeroes as fractions of second.

In this case, a pattern such as `yyyyMMddHHmmssSS` won't work due to a [bug in Java 8 API](http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=8031085).

The same link above also provides the workaround: use a `java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder` with a `java.time.temporal.ChronoField` for the fraction of seconds.

```
String dateStr = "2017101800000700";
DateTimeFormatter fmt = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    // date/time
    .appendPattern("yyyyMMddHHmmss")
    // milliseconds (with 2 digits)
    .appendValue(ChronoField.MILLI_OF_SECOND, 2)
    // create formatter
    .toFormatter();
System.out.println(LocalDateTime.parse(dateStr, fmt)); // 2017-10-18T00:00:07
```

This will parse the following `LocalDateTime`:

> 2017-10-18T00:00:07

Note that it's different from the previous one, because now we're considering `07` to be the seconds.